# When uploading a file is_uploaded_file returns false?

Tags: php, file-upload

im using a simple input file type to upload a pdf to the server:

```
<form action="subirCircular.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input type="file" name="userfile" accept="application/pdf">
     <br><br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subir</button>
</form>
```

And I receive the file in the php for uploading:

```
<?php
 define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./uploads/");

   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

      if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
         echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
      } else {
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY."/$name.pdf");
         if ($result == 1) echo "<p>File successfully uploaded.</p>";
         else echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the file.</p>";
      } #endIF
   }else{
       echo 'ERROR!';
       }


?>
```

The thing is the condition never gets called, I always get a false 'is_uploaded_file'.

I would like to know what Im doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: How big is the file, and what is the max upload limit in your PHP configuration? [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Im uploading a test pdf file of less than 1 mb, my php config is set to 25 MB

Comment: What does `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` tell you?

Comment: Sorry, how can I get that? `echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];`?

Answer (score 1):

I rather use :

```
$_FILES['userfile']['error']
```

to check if every thing is ok, and if yes then I use

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$pathname)
```

to move the uploaded file.
And so far it works.

Answer (score -1):

Check your request method - it should be POST, not PUT/PATCH/...